# What is the automorphism group of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I know that the automorphism group of the projective space $\mathbb P^n$ is $PGL(n+1)$.  What is it for $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$?  Apart from individual automorphisms of the factors $\mathbb P^1$, there is the *switch* automorphism as well.  I do not know how to incorporate this and write down the automorphism group.  Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slick way (edit: not as slick as I thought!) to answer this is to use the *Picard group* of $\mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1$, that is, the group of line bundles, or linear equivalence classes of divisors. (If there's an easier way, I'd be glad to hear it.)

In this case we have $\operatorname{Pic} \left( \mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1 \right) \cong \mathbf Z \oplus \mathbf Z$, with generators given by the classes of the divisors $\pi_1^* (p)$ and $\pi_2^* (p)$, the pullback of a point from either of the two factors.

Now any automorphism of the variety must induce an automorphism of the Picard group, but moreover it must send *effective divisors to effective divisors*.  It's not hard to check that any such automorphism must either preserve the generators above, or switch them.

First suppose $\phi$ is an automorphism that preserves the generators of the Picard group. Then it preserves the fibres of the maps $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$, and so it induces automorphisms of the two $\mathbf P^1$ factors. Moreover $\phi$ is determined by its action on those two factors, so the subgroup of such automorphisms is $PGL(2) \times PGL(2)$.

Finally, denote the switch automorphism $(p,q) \mapsto (q,p)$ by $s$. If $\phi$ is an automorphism that switches the generators of the Picard group, then $s \circ \phi$ is an automorphism that preserves them, so $s \circ \phi \in PGL(2) \times PGL(2)$. But $s$ is an involution, so $\phi = s \circ (s \circ \phi)$. So the automorphism group is a (nonabelian) $\mathbf Z_2$-extension of $PGL(2) \times PGL(2)$.

**Supplementary remark:** I suppose another argument would be to observe that $\mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1$ is isomorphic to a smooth quadric in $\mathbf P^3$, and any automorphism of the quadric comes from an automorphism of the ambient space (because the quadric is embedded by a multiple of $-K$). One could then identify the subgroup of $PGL(4)$ preserving the quadratic form, and show it's isomorphic to the group I wrote down. Offhand, I don't know if this is easier or harder than the first method.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  So the answer is $\mathbb Z_2 \rtimes PGL(2)\times PGL(2)$?

Comment: Dear @Paul, that's right. (I suppose to be precise one needs to specify how the $\mathbf Z_2$ is acting on the other group.)

Comment: Hi, isn't it in the other direction? It looks like $\mathrm{PGL}(2) \times \mathrm{PGL}(2)$ is the normal subgroup so the group should be the extension of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, i.e. $\mathrm{PGL}(2) \times \mathrm{PGL}(2) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.